# How can I split and give uppercase to a string at the same time?

Tags: python, string, split, uppercase

I have this string, I am fairly new to python and I just need help doing this.

def this_sentence(My friend went on a tour)

I want the Output to look like this
['MY', 'FRIEND', 'WENT', 'ON', 'A', 'TOUR']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) to make all characters uppercase and then [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the words at each space.

```
def this_sentence(sentence):
    return sentence.upper().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a separate function, just use `split()` and `upper()`:

```py
split_sentence = [word.upper() for word in sentence.split()]
```

Comment: Why not `split_sentence = sentence.upper().split()`?

Comment: That's way more efficient, actually. Forgot `split()` itself returns an array.

Comment: It returns a _list_ (there is a difference between the two, and terminology is important) :)

Comment: Didn't know the two were _that_ different, looked it up and what do you know. Learn something new every day :)